# (Python) - Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, парсер

Парсер работал, но вдруг стал выдавать ошибку:

[image: Error: NoneType object has no attribute text]

Мой код:

```
    def get_third_url(self):
    log.info('Парсим')
    text = self.session.get('https://u.to/ofd6Gw').text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
    pagination = int(soup.select('div.page-navigation a')[-2].text)
    for page in range(1, pagination + 1):
        log.info(f'Страница {page}/{pagination}')
        if page != 1:
            text = self.session.get('https://u.to/ofd6Gw',
                                    params={'PAGEN_2': page}).text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
        urls = list(map(lambda x: 'https://u.to/v1qrGw' + x.get('href'),
                        soup.select('div.bordered.product_name a')))
        for url in urls:
            text = self.session.get(url).text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
            category = list(map(lambda x: x.text, soup.select('div.bx-breadcrumb-item span')[2:-2]))

            if all(list(
                    map(lambda x: True if x.replace('/', '').strip() not in setting.not_parsing_category else False,
                        category))):
                category = ' '.join(category)
                name = soup.select_one('div.name').text
                meta = soup.select('div.bx_rt meta')[0].get('content')
                articul = meta.replace(name, '').replace('NORDBERG', '').replace('Nordberg', '').split('(')[
                    0].strip()
                if articul == '':
                    continue
                brand = 'Nordberg'
                characteristics = list(filter(lambda x: True if x != '' and x != u'\xa0' else False, list(
                    map(lambda x: x.text, soup.select('div.properties-tth table td')))))
                characteristics = list(
                    characteristics[i] + ': ' + characteristics[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(characteristics), 2))
                info = soup.select_one('div.tab.tab-description.current')
                info = info.text.split('\n') if info is not None else []

                short_info = []
                len_ = 0
                for i in range(len(info)):
                    if len_ + len(info[i]) <= 350:
                        len_ += len(info[i])
                        if i == len(info) - 1:
                            short_info = info[::]
                    else:
                        short_info = info[:i]
                        break
                info.extend(characteristics)
                short_info = '<div class="offers_info_list">' + ''.join(
                    list(map(lambda x: '<p>' + x.strip() + '</p>', short_info))) + '</div>'
                info = '<div class="offers_info_card">' + ''.join(
                    list(map(lambda x: '<p>' + x.strip() + '</p>', info))) + '</div>'
                images = list(
                    map(lambda x: 'https://u.to/v1qrGw' + x.get('style').replace(
                        "background-image:url('",
                        '').replace("');", ''),
                        soup.select('span.cnt_item')[:4]))

                if images:
                    main_image = images[0]
                    dop_images = '|'.join(images[1:])
                else:
                    main_image = ''
                    dop_images = ''
                price = ''.join(soup.select_one('span.price-label').text.split(' ')[:-1]).strip().replace(' ', '')
                if price != '':
                    price = int(price)
                else:
                    continue
                self.result.append(
                    [category, name, brand, articul, short_info, info, main_image, dop_images, price, 'nordberg'])
    log.info('УСПЕШНО')
```

Пожалуйста подскажите в чем допускаю ошибку, хотя все работало и сейчас работает но на 28-29 стр., останавливается.

Спасибо!

Comment: Ну вам же там пишется в какой строке ошибка. Вот и смотрите, что в той строке может быть `None`. Вероятно, какой-то элемент не находится. Сохраните эту страницу и проанализируйте, что там не так.

Comment: Строку не вижу, если вы про цифру 206, то на всех страницах одинаковая, там стоит скрипт Яндекс и не более.